# Existence of bases with respect to the matrix of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$
Let $f\in \Hom_\RR(\RR^n, \RR^m)$. Let $A = M(f)$ be the matrix of this transformation in the standard basis.

Is it true or false (I can't find a counterexample):

> For any matrix $B$ such that $\rank A = \rank B $ there exists such bases $X,Y$ of $\RR^n, \RR^m$ respectively that $B = M(f)^Y_X$

or equivalently

> For any matrix $B$ such that $\rank A = \rank B $ there exist isomorphic matrices $C,D$ [change of basis matrices] such that $B = C \cdot A \cdot D$

If the statement is false, can we strengthen our assumptions to get a true theorem?

$M(f)_X^Y$ signifies a matrix of the transformation $f$ in bases $X,Y$